# mysqli_stmt_bind_param error - mismatch number of parameters

Tags: php

I have this code in php

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "
    select e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.hire_date, d.dept_name
    from employee e, department d
    where e.dept_id = d.dept_id and (e.first_name like '%(?)%' or e.last_name like '%(?)%')");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $key, $key);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

I have two "?" and I ask for two variables. Why does it not get it? I am a total noob in php so please be patient if it seems ridiculous to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to search for? The key, or the key with parentheses around it or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you have 0 `?`s and 2 parameters.  The `?`s only work *outside* of a string.  `mysqli_prepare` is interpreting `'%(?)%'` not as a placeholder, but just as a string.

You need to add the `%` to the variable you are binding... like this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "
    select e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.hire_date, d.dept_name
    from employee e, department d
    where e.dept_id = d.dept_id and (e.first_name like ? or e.last_name like ?)");
$likeKey = "%{$key}%";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $likeKey, $likeKey);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

You just put the `?` in the query.  Not in quotes.  That's done for you.

P.S. You don't need the `()` in the `like` string (unless it's actually part of the value you are looking for).  In `like` the parenthesis are interpreted literally and have *no* special meaning.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows doesn't print the results?

Comment: @BillyGrande: No.  It's not supposed to.  That's only for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` (and possibly `DELETE`).  You haven't "affected" any rows, only selected them.  Check the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php), to get the count of rows returned, use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`.  If you want the *result*, then you need to use `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`.